# AWS OIDC policy for multiple repositories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, identity-management, aws-policies

I am trying to allow access to an AWS service for Github Actions in *multiple repositories* via OIDC. Here is the current policy that works with 1 repository:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<id>:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:username/myrepo:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, how can we allow this policy for multiple repositories? Duplicating `"token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:username/myrepo:*"` does not seem to work, the console editor shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use multiple possible values for same key, you need to use arrays:

```
"StringLike": {
    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": [
        "repo:username/myrepo1:*",
        "repo:username/myrepo2:*"
        ]
    }
```

With multiple values for the same context key, AWS is evaluating that with OR, so this would allow access from `myrepo1` and `myrepo2`